# Express, mongoose: I want to 'req.body' inside an object, but I have no idea how to do it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, object, mongoose

I am learning how to use Express with mongoDB, but I have a problem when I want to concatenate a req.body inside an object and I don't know with what arguments to specify it.

pd.1: Is my first request for help on stackoverflow.

pd.2: I've already googled, I usually find the solution in other Stackoverflow threads.

My scheme works in its entirety, I have already done petitions in 'Postman'.
Here's the schema

```
const clothesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {type: String, required: [true, 'The type of clothe is necesary']},
    color: {type: String, required: [true, 'The color is necessary']},
    price: {type: Number, required: [true, 'The price is necessary']},
    image: {type: String, required: [true, 'The image is necessary ']},
    size_S: {
        size: {type: String, required: true, default: () => {return "S"}},
        quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
    },
    size_M: {
        talla: {type: String, required: true, default: () => {return "M"}},
        quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
    },
    size_L: {
        talla: {type: String, required: true, default: () => {return "L"}},
        quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
    },
})
```

Heres the Route and the heelp what i need

```
// Create New Clothe 

router.route("/new").post((req, res) => {
  let db = new Clothes();

  db.type = req.body.type;
  db.color = req.body.color;
  db.price = req.body.price;
  db.image = req.body.image;

// -------------- Need help or recommendations for this arguments  ----------------
  db.size_S = {
    quantity: req.body.quantity
  };
  db.size_M = {
    quantity: req.body.quantity
  };
  db.size:L ={
    quantity: req.body.quantity
  };
 
db.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      response = { error: true, msg: "Something was wrong" };
    } else {
      response = { error: true, msg: "New clothe Succesfully created" };
    }
    res.json(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear in terms of what you want to achieve. What do you mean by 'Want to argument' ?

Comment: My English is not very good.
I want to "concatenate"
quantity in db.size _S, db.size M and db.size _L, because it doesn't return what I expect in my response.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I wanted to concatenate quantity on db.size_S for body request

My attempt:

```
db.size_S = {
     quantity: req.body.quantity
};
```

After hours of multiple attempts I reached the
answer I was looking for

The solution I got:

```
db.size_S = req.body.size_S
```

When i doing `req.body.size_S`, I also call the arguments inside `size_S` scheema, the request in Postman has Succesfully completed!